# Different Sort Order on Distinct types

Tags: php, sorting

Is there an elegant way to sort a string differently based on its type?

For example, say I have the following data:

```
AB421
4TS3
4A521
6ACD
4R3
6BCE
4F
```

and I need to sort numbers on descending order, and letters on ascending order.

The above should be sorted like so:

```
AB421
6ACD
6BCE
4A521
4F
4R3
4TS3
```

See that 6, 4 is numerically descending, but the letters are in ascending order. If a letter and number is being compared, the letter needs to be the first.

The only way I can think of is using a custom callback sort function that would str_split my strings and compare everything by hand, checking it's type in the process. But this seem unwieldy and I'm not sure if there's a clever php sort to solve this.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two sorting functions uksort() and usort() in php that take user defined compare functions.

In your case, if the sorting data are values of an array, you can use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php).
Just define the compare function depending on your sorting demands:

- number<->number
- number<->string
- string<->number
- string<->string

Some examples on how to define sorting functions you can find in the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a recursive usort() and a custom comparator function.  This function compares left-most characters of the strings according to your rules, then if the characters are the same, it recursively runs the same function on both strings shifted one character to the right.

Run it, it works perfectly.

```
<?php

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if($a[0] == $b[0]) {
        return cmp(substr($a,1), substr($b,1));
    } else if(is_numeric($a[0]) == is_numeric($b[0])) {
        //this is where you compare numbers to numbers and letters to letters.
        if(is_numeric($a[0])) {
            return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    } else if(is_numeric($a[0]) && !is_numeric($b[0])) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

$a = array(
"AB421",
"4TS3",
"4A521",
"6ACD",
"4R3",
"6BCE",
"4F"
);

print_r($a);

usort($a, "cmp");

print_r($a);

?>
```

Output for this program is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AB421
    [1] => 4TS3
    [2] => 4A521
    [3] => 6ACD
    [4] => 4R3
    [5] => 6BCE
    [6] => 4F
)
Array
(
    [0] => AB421
    [1] => 6ACD
    [2] => 6BCE
    [3] => 4A521
    [4] => 4F
    [5] => 4R3
    [6] => 4TS3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write own function for sorting.

It is easy for you and can understand what you are doing.

It can be use anywhere.

```
 function mySort ($input) {

     $numberArray = array();
     $stringArray = array();

     foreach($inputas $c) {
            $tt = substr($c, 0, 1);

            if (is_numeric($tt)) {
                $numberArray[] = $c;
            } else {
                $stringArray[] = $c;
            }
      }

       sort($stringArray);
       rsort($numberArray);
       $newArray = array_merge($stringArray, $numberArray);

       return $newArray;

  }
```

Example:

```
  $cars=array(
     "AB421",
     "YB421",
     "4TS3",
     '4A521',
     "6ACD",
     "4R3",
     "6BCE",
     "4F"
  );
```

$s = mySort($cars);